# Trying to get Ajax Form to Submit Only After jQuery Validation

Tags: ajax, validation, jquery, jquery-mobile

I can't seem to figure out how to get my Ajax form to only submit when the jQuery validation function has taken place. Here is my code...

http://jsfiddle.net/gbaH7/16/

This is the validation plugin I'm using, http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
$("#contactForm").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        console.log("Call Login Action");
    }
});
```

should be inside `$(document).ready(function() {`. Worked for me.

Comment: It is still firing the form to my email, without it being validated first.
http://jsfiddle.net/gbaH7/18/

Comment: Move everything from `$("#submit").click(function(){` into `submitHandler`. Validate plugin does not intercepts onclick events.